# Найти ошибку в коде программы

Tags: c

Добрый день Программа должна высчитывать определитель квадратной матрицы, размер которой вводится с клавиатуры, но при n > 2 программа высчитывает ее неправильно.
К примеру, для матрицы:

```
41 67 34
 0 69 24
78 58 62
```

Определитель должен равняться 60762, но программа выводит 79212.

Код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int n;
  printf("Vvedite razmer n kvadratnoi matrici: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
  int a[n][n], d = 1, r = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      a[i][j] = rand() % 100;
      printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  if (n == 1)
  {
    d = a[0][0];
    printf("Opredelitel matrici raven - %d", d);
    return 0;
  }
  if (n == 2)
  {
    d = a[0][0] * a[1][1] - (a[1][0] * a[0][1]);
    printf("Opredelitel matrici raven - %d", d);
    return 0;
  }
  if (n > 2)
  {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      {
        if (j > i)
        {
          r = a[j][i] / a[i][i];
          for (k = 0; k < n; k++) a[j][k] -= r * a[i][k];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) d *= a[i][i];
  printf("Opredelitel matrici raven - %d", d);
  return 0;
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку.

Comment: Всем: вопрос похож на домашку, потому что  совсем недавно был точно такой же вопрос.

Comment: Я просто пересоздал этот вопрос, а старый удалил.

Comment: Там изначально вопрос состоял в том, что программа вообще не выводила значение определителя из-за очень глупой ошибки, на которую мне и указали, а потом я уже просто отредактировал вопрос, ибо возникла проблема описанная в данном вопросе.

Comment: Так проблема та же самая, что и в том вопросе? По крайней мере я его видел именно в такой же формулировке.

Comment: По итогу да. Как я уже говорил, там изначально была описана другая проблема, на которую и был дан ответ.

Comment: А, понятно теперь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше как `d` так и `r` сделать вещественными числами, а не целыми. Т.к. при делении целых чисел отбрасывается дробная часть.

Так же можно вместо проверки `if (j > i)` написать вот так:

```
double r = 0;
double d = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        r = a[j][i] / a[i][i];
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) 
            a[j][k] -= r * a[i][k];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы всё заработало нужно сделать вещественными `d`, `r`, `a` и поправить операторы печати. Вы делите целые числа, при делении остатки отбрасываются, что приводит к неправильным результатам:

```
// int a[n][n], d = 1, r = 0;
double a[n][n], d = 1, r = 0;
```

Я ещё рекомендую убрать специальную обработку для `n = 1, n = 2`. Она лишняя, затрудняет отладку общего случая.

Общие слова: метод Гаусса для целочисленных матриц не подходит, нужны дроби, знаменатели которых будут быстро расти и вызывать переполнение. Если матрицы не большие, то определитель считается разложением по строке.